# How to iterate over a table of dates in PostgreSQL, summing total weekdays in each month

Tags: postgresql

I need help with what I presume is a stored procedure in Postgres.

I need a view of dates, appended to which is a running count of weekdays within each month (resetting on the 1st of each month).

I am creating a view (in query) using:

```
with dates as (
select 
generate_series('2018-01-01', current_date - 1, interval '1 day')::date 
as _day
order by 1 asc
)
```

The output will look something like this:

```
January 1st 2018 | Monday | 1
January 2nd 2018 | Tuesday| 2
January 3rd 2018 | Wednesday | 3
January 4th 2018 | Thursday | 4
January 5th 2018 | Friday | 5
January 6th 2018 | Saturday | 5
January 7th 2018 | Sunday | 5
...
February 1st 2018 | Thursday | 1
```

Key being that non-weekdays (weekends) do not increment and the count resets on the first of each month.

Thank you!
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with dates as (
  select generate_series('2018-01-01', current_date - 1, interval '1 day')::date as _day order by 1 asc
)
select 
  _day,
  sum(case when date_part('dow', _day) in (1,2,3,4,5) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date_part('month', _day) order by _day)
from dates;
```